# How to prevent anonymous users from accessing a file using forms authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, forms-authentication, virtual-directory

We are using forms authentication to authenticate users. In our application there is a page to download an exe.

When I am debugging the code in visual studio, it allows only logged-in users to download the file. When other users try to download the file, they are automatically redirected to the login page.

But when I am running this from a virtual directory, all users (whether logged-in or not) can download the file by accessing the direct path like `http://testappln/foldername/test.exe`.

How to prevent accessing of unauthorized users in this situation?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using? If you are using IIS 7.0+ are you running in classic or in integrated mode? How can a user possibly access `C:\foldername\test.exe` on the server from his browser?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: sorry.. i changed the path..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to put the file inside the `App_Data` folder which is forbidden direct access to and then have a generic ASHX handler to read the contents of the file and return it to the client. Then you could restrict the access to this generic handler to only authenticated users:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Download" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Download : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.WriteFile("~/App_Data/test.exe");
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and in your web.config you restrict the access to the `Download.ashx` handler:

```
<location path="Download.ashx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: if i am downloading the file like this from javascript window.open('http://testappln/foldername/test.exe','Download'), then how can i handle this case?

Comment: @mahesh, like this: `window.open('download.ashx','Download');`.

Answer (score 1):

a very simple approach is to use IIS to prevent anonymous access to a folder.
just open IIS, select your site and select the folder which you want to secure it.
after selecting the folder, double click on Authentication (in IIS section) in the Authentication page disable Anonymous Authentication.
By now only your site authenticated users can access to your selected folder.