# ASP.NET returns 401 Unauthorized for a file even when web.config is set up to allow it?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization

I'm probably missing something easy here, but I have an ASP.NET website that uses Identity and roles, and I'm trying to restrict access to a folder containing some MP4 videos so that anonymous users cannot see direct links to those videos.

I had this in my web.config for the folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow roles="Admin"/>
          <allow roles="User"/>
          <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The asp:LoginView control works fine with this setup, but the videos return a 401 error.

I tried this as well with the same result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If I remove everything from the authorization tag, then it works so I know all the paths are right and something about the authorization setup is preventing it from serving that video.

I also tried calling out the Files directory individually like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin"/>
            <allow roles="User"/>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="Files">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately, this makes it so that I can access the video link even when not logged in (which is what I am trying to prevent).

If I try to do a role based setup for the Files subfolder like this (which I don't think should be any different from the first version) then I'm back to getting a 401 on the video, even when logged in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Admin"/>
            <allow roles="User"/>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <location path="Files">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow roles="Admin"/>
                <allow roles="User"/>
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my answer. I think the following is what you are looking for:

[How to prevent anonymous users from accessing a file using forms authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837846/how-to-prevent-anonymous-users-from-accessing-a-file-using-forms-authentication)

Comment: The cookie system is working fine, I can log in and out without problems. What I am trying to do is control access to a certain folder to prevent anonymous users from direct linking to a file, and it is not working how I would expect.

Comment: See my modified answer.

Comment: Thank you, I think this gives me the information to do what I was trying to do.

Comment: @Jamal, nice that you were able to help the original poster (OP). However, your answer can be improved. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and/or [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)